# K2 Categories Upload Image

Tags: k2, joomla-3.5

This never happneded to me before, I can't open the "Browse Server" box to search the image and upload. For some reason, I upload image from PC and when I save changes, it doesn't record the image uploaded. So, basically I'm not able to upload images from "Browse Server" neither uploading from PC. This only happens in K2 Categories.

In K2 Items I can upload via "Browse Server", but can't upload from PC.

Tried to find similar problems and couldn't find why I can't open "Browse Server" in K2 Categories.

I am using Joomla 3.5 and K2 v2.7.0

UPDATE: I can now upload images from PC after editing file 'category.php', replacing '===' by '=='. Although can't open dialog search from Server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have cleared both your browser cache and your Joomla cache, I can think of 2 reasons causing this:

- You have installed a system plugin lately that is causing a conflict. Uninstall the plugins that you have installed lately one by one.
- Your website is hacked.

Check the console in Google Chrome (press F12) to see which errors are being reported.